# Understanding the parent child relationship (fixed blocks) CSS

Tags: css

I've been enjoying and having success mocking up webpages with CSS. But then I decided to play with a "fixed menu" and my understanding is now not so clear.

So my brief knowledge make a blank HTML doc and then create a "container" div and place all your further elements within the "parent" container. No problem with this and all has been well with floating elements and such.

But when placing a "fixed" element within my parent div I'm lost as to why the fixed element observes the parent's left margin and ignores it's right margin.

```css
html, body{margin: 0; padding: 0;}

#container
{
margin:0px auto;
width:90%;
height:500px;
background:#A8A8A8;
}

.fixed-menu
{
position: fixed;
height: 50px;
width:100%;
background-color: #00a087;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="container">

<div class="fixed-menu"></div>

</div>
</body>
```

So with the above the "fixed" block does align with the left margin of the parent container but runs completely to the right edge of the browser page. I have figured out that I can make the fixed block 90% and resolve the issue but I don't understand why. Why would the block not be 90% of the parent "container" block.

I look forward to you knowledge. 
Thanks

Comment: This behavior is correct. A fixed element ignores its container and also the scrollbar: its fixed on a **screen** position. Maybe you had 'static' in mind and wrote it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your css like below to achieve your desired result. Inherit your width from the parent instead of using 100%.

```
.fixed-menu
{
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width:inherit;
  left:auto;
  right:auto;
  background-color: #00a087;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/9juLddjk/1/)

Comment: This has both resolved my question and explained it. I have not yet had to deal with the "inherit" rule. But your help certainly explains it and opens more opportunities to work with this rule. Thank you.

Comment: So with you helpful answers it leads me to yet another question. Obviously the first element on the page needs to clear the fixed element (in this case 50px). What is the best way to achieve this? Add 50px padding or margin to the parent element or perhaps with a hidden 50px element?

Answer (score 0):

as stated by @freestock.tk, a fixed element is "fixed" to the screen viewport.
the width (and height of set in %) is computed relative to the screen viewport.

it looks like it's aligned to left margin of the parent container because you did not positioned it with left or right css properties, it's not constrained by the parent container, it is just at the same horizontal position in this peculiar case.

if you set

left:0;

it will align to the left margin of the viewport and ignore the parent container, this should help you better understand his fixed positioning.

```css
html, body{margin: 0; padding: 0;}

#container
{
margin:0px auto;
width:90%;
height:500px;
background:#A8A8A8;
}

.fixed-menu
{
position: fixed;
left:0;
height: 50px;
width:100%;
background-color: #00a087;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="container">

<div class="fixed-menu"></div>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is yet more understanding of "fixed" elements.

Answer (score -2):

You where almost there, just add to `.fixed-menu` few css rules more :

```
.fixed-menu {
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 95% // now you can change width and fixed element will be centered always
}
```

Comment: That sure did fix the problem but I'm not really sure why. Does the "left:0" and "right:0" tell the element to recognize the parent element?

Comment: Sorry, but with further testing this was not the correct solution.